# Is method overloading a form of polymorphism or something else?

Tags: java, oop, overloading

I have a long standing doubt. Could someone please tell me whether method overloading is a form of polymorphism or is it something completely different?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Method Overloading considered polymorphism?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400284/is-method-overloading-considered-polymorphism)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Method **overloading** is just a syntax sugar allowing you to have methods with same name but different arguments. It has nothing to do with polymorphism. Method overloading is typically used to define two methods accepting different arguments, e.g.:

```
public void println(boolean x) //...
public void println(char x) //...
```

or to skip certain parameters and use some defaults:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex) //...
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) //...
```

Method **overriding**, on the other hand, is a foundation of inheritance and is more closely related to polymorphism.

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz, what about method hiding. is it considered polymorphism?

Answer (score 4):

**Polymorphism**, literally means something which has **multiple behavior.**

In java, we can have a static and runtime polymorphism.

**Overloading** is static polymorphism since it allows different behavior by means of passing varying arguments. But this is resolved at the complile time only, hence static.

**Overriding**, is dynamic polymorphism since the actual call to the function depends on the type of object invoking it which is available only at the runtime, hence dynamic.

Comment: so you are contradicting all the above comments ?

Comment: @user581544 : its my opinion and what i have read in past years.. Frankly I do relate both of above to polymorphic behavior..

Answer (score 1):

No, its not, it's method overloading.

java does polymorphism via interfaces. It has no multiple inheritance.

You can, however, simulate multiple inhertance by using multiple interface and the composite/delegate pattern.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not related to object oriented programming. Overloading simply means that you can use the same name for different method signatures.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not.

With *overloading* you just provide different implementations of a same method name with different signatures.

Since *polymorphism* (by subtyping) requires the same signature (that is made either by method name either by parameters) then the two things can never intersect.