# Java : What is the difference between the below object creation methodologies in terms of programing usage?

Tags: java, inheritance, instance

```
public class SuperClass {}
public class ChildClass extends SuperClass {}

SuperClass  A = new ChildClass();

ChildClass B  = new ChildClass();
```

With both the instances A & B, we can only access the protected methods of super class . Then what is the difference between the two and which places they come into use ? Thanks in advance

Comment: No, with `B` you can access all the public methods of `ChlidClass` as well. I would leave `protected` out of it at the moment, as that's a more complex set of rules...

Comment: This is Dynamic binding/Runtime binding/Method overriding.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783266/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-static-polymorphism-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's matter of what additional public methods B will provide compared to A and how the client code will use the instance created.

If you take the `List` and `ArrayList` (`List` is an interface but it's valid for the example), very often you will choose the class implementation for its own capabilities: `ArrayList` is an auto-increasing vector that provide constant access to its elements. But the client of the class may not really care about the kind of `List` implementation, and you will have more flexibility to just use this instance as a simple `List` that provide the list *abstraction*.

Another case is about polymorphism. If you extends your example with an other class, e.g.

```
 public class AnotherChildClass extends SuperClass {}
```

And you need to process a list of objects from the 2 child classes, e.g.

```
List<SuperClass> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(new ChildClass());
myList.add(new AnotherChildClass());
myList.add(new ChildClass());
//...

// later
(for (SuperClass s : myList) {
   s.doSomeThing();
}
```

provided the method `doSomeThing()` has been declared in `SuperClass` and implemented by both children classes (or implemented in `SuperClass` and possibly overridden).

Your question relates to a fundamental part of OOP which is [abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29#Abstraction_in_object_oriented_programming).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation   I just wanted to see an example scenario where they use it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

```
a.getClass().getName();
```

Why does this matter?

```
public class SuperClass {}
public class SonClass extends SuperClass {}
public class DaughterClass extends SuperClass {}

SuperClass[] Arr = new SuperClass[2];
Arr[0] = new SonClass();
Arr[1] = new DaughterClass()
```