# Declared base class/interface or implementation when creating objects?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Here I have this question. Let's say code 1 is *Java with runtime polymorphism* and code 2 is *Java without runtime polymorphism*.

Code 1:

```
class A {
    void run() { System.out.println("A is running"); }
}

class B extends A{
    void run(){ System.out.println("B is running with A!");}

    public static void main(String args[]){

        A a = new B(); //referenced to class A
        a.run();

    }
}
```

Code 2:

```
class A {
    void run(){System.out.println("A is running");}
}

class B extends A{
    void run(){ System.out.println("B is running with A!");}

    public static void main(String args[]){
        B a = new B(); //referenced to the same constructor class
        a.run();
    }
}
```

Even though these two codes give the exact same results, it is well known that runtime polymorphism is really important in OOP. I need an explanation/reason of using code 1 instead of using code 2.

Comment: run-time polymorphism is really helpful where multiple different objet inherits from the same class and you got to store them in a single array

Comment: Your example doesn't motivate the usage of runtime polymorphism.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783266/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-static-polymorphism-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of polymorphism is not needed in OOP in every cases.
Polymorphism  is a mechanism which brings flexibility when flexibility is needed.

For example, in your case, writing :

```
B a = new B();
```

or

```
A a = new B()
```

depends if you need and have interest to reference the base class rather than the subclass as declared type for your variable.

Referencing the base class (here `A`) allows many things among these (it is not exhaustive but frequent use cases) :

- masking the implementation (via factory or injection dependency). In this way, you can change the implementation (returning a `C` or `D` which extends `A`) without breaking calls of client code. In your code, you don't perform that but in real applications you can have this need.
- If you have processings common to `A` and `B` classes, you may propose a method which takes as parameter a instance of type `A`. 
  Example `: public void doProcess(A instance)`
  In this case, if you declare `B a = new B()`, the code will not compile
  if you pass this instance to that method as  semantically, a `B` instance is a `A` but a `A` instance is not
  necessarily a `B`

Often, we can read that declaring the interface rather that the implementation is a good practice. In fact, it is in most of cases but in some other cases, it is not. Just one example, if you need to use a `TreeMap`, you will not declare the interface `Map` because the behavior of `TreeMap` is very specific and have special requirements, so you may want to stress on. When you instantiate a classic `HashMap`, generally, you don't care precising `HashMap` as declared type  since  its interface is enough. You have no interest to create a stronger coupling with the implementation.

Comment: This helps a lot! Thanks

Comment: You are welcome :)  You are right to wonder about the subject since polymorphism  is one of key of OOP languages :)
If I addressed your question, feel free to mark  my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this case :
You have multiple classes inheriting from the same base class, you want to call their shared function `run()` on all of them, even though they are different classes.
You'll have to do this:

```
interface A{
    void run();
}

class B implements A{
void run(){ System.out.println("B is running with A!");}

class C implements A{
void run(){ System.out.println("C is running with A!");}

public static void main(String args[]){
    Array<A> objects = new Array<A>();
    objects.put(new B()); //Object are stored as instances of "A"
    objects.put(new C());
    objects.put(new B());
    for (A obj : objects)
        obj.run();//Calls everything
}
```